# How to embed Google Analytics charts on my website?

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm building an admin panel, and I would like to put the system of google Analytics inside it, login automatically with a predefined email. Something like putting an iframe, or other solution provided by Google. Someone knows something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you want to show Google Analytics charts on an admin panel of your site?  If so check out [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  Purpose of the service is to do exactly this; but without getting into the workings of the API.  You simply define your chart and copy a iframe snippet of code where you want it to show.

*(Disclosure: I created the service)*

Comment: Ok, i saw it, thanks by your answer, but it is payd. Well, i think that i will be passing for my client the password to acces the Analytcs direct by the site. Ty!

Comment: EmbeddedAnalytics is a paid service.  But if your site has less than 2,000 unique visits per month it can be used for free.  As far as sharing the password, this is not required.  The service employs Google's Authentication where you grant us access to the data through a revokable token.  We never have access to the user name and password.

Answer (score 0):

It's no easy business. Google provides an [API for Analytics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/) which you can [retrieve data](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html) from, amongst other things.

Once you've got the data using the API, you can do what ever you like with it.

Comment: Well, i think it will be more easy pass the google anlytcs url... :D
Anyway, Thank you!